# How can I find the popped up QFiledialog when I click file input in the QWebView?

Tags: qt, qwebview, qfiledialog, input-type-file

```
QApplication.postEvent(object, press)
```

I want to simulate the keypress and mousepress in the select file dialog, which is popped up by clicking file input in the `QWebView`. I don't know what the object is. Any ideas on how to obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

Make a stock `QFileDialog` in another project, and dump its Object Tree.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Hope that helps.